# Why is not there encrypted way of sharing/showing data such as Password to the user (hidden from web app Source code)?

Tags: encryption, passwords, web-application, browser-extensions

I wonder if there will be (or is) a way to hide data such as passwords from the HTML/DOM structure? As, password fields can hide from external person other than the main user with something like "••••••••" but this does not prevent anyone or any extension that has access from inspecting HTML code.

(I am not fully web-dev) I am looking around comparing open-source password managers and I am looking at Psono and Passbolt. Passbolt does not add the password value to the HTML code until user clicks view button which is improves security, but the former does not and is not "good" (I still thanks their efforts and for existing, I just happen to use them as an example now). My concern here is mainly with chrome and probably other browsers' extensions, because some naïve users have all kinds of extensions, that may be scraping through such pages collecting such security data. This concerns me, as password managers or any other WEB-based apps have potential attack from such extensions.

Should not there already a way around this? Why are some things left up to the user to decide? There should have been by now, standard browser-wide security feature such as password fields whose values are not visible in the HTML or the DOM but are visible to the user. (Normally, in native desktop application (such as DotNet/Java based) there is no source inspection available (after it is released as EXEcutable), or if your application allows plugins, it is up to you to decide what you can allow the extensions to access.)

Comment: [Bitwarden](https://github.com/bitwarden) is another teams-friendly FOSS pw manager that only populates a pw when prompted. A password has to exist in the DOM at some point unless you have another way to submit it. If just before submission is insufficient, maybe you'd prefer a solution involving cryptographic keys like [client certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate#TLS/SSL_client_certificate), [hardware tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_token), or [HOTP.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC-based_one-time_password)

Comment: @AdamKatz yes I have heard of Bitwarden, I will check it. And yes that’s what I assumed and how the standard is at this time, that any **value** must exist in DOM at some point.  I think future standards should consider either storage of secret values separately or restrict extensions access to “special” fields. Unless there’s adverse side effects to such features.

Comment: We have those standards now. They involve cryptographic keys or one-time passwords, as I mentioned earlier. These solve the issue of password compromise in more places than browser extensions since the key itself is never distributed. They also solve the issue with people choosing abysmally insecure passwords.

Comment: @AdamKatz, after researching about these, I get what you mean. However, these are useful for up coming/future projects, there are too many existing websites that rely on simple password auth, thus, providing more secure way of handling passwords/secrets in browsers should probably be priority. Realising this, the solution can only probably be client-based, being extra-careful with dev-tools and extensions and requiring no change whatsoever to existing websites/apps (otherwise there will be too many out of date sites). That said, I can now assume my answer.

Comment: Yes, this could conceivably be implemented at the client level if a new browser extension had the ability to insert the pw and submit the POST action, but there is no such implementation and that would only solve one of the many security concerns existing solutions like a key or OTP would solve. If you're so concerned, maybe you should lock down your users' browsers and limit their extensions.

Comment: Yes, potentially at the company level, some steps could be taken like disabling extensions and applying all kinds of security standards. However, my main concern is for the general and common users, including myself where I tend to use various "safe" extensions.

Comment: What you just mentioned, I think the browser has a lot more power and ultimately it is the only deciding factor. It is often the case that pw are needed to be displayed to the user, it is not only on form submission, so it could implement a feature that would hide the value, and extensions such as PW Managers could interact with these kinds of values via an API without needing to know.